# How to programmatically add PictureBox control to the tab page control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I programmatically add a `PictureBox` control to a `TabPage` control and fit to its size?

Comment: Look at the way the designer does it and just copy its code.  Open the Designer.cs file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tabPage.Controls.Add(pb);
```

Answer (score 3):

The code would be look like:

```
        var pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(@"\\filepath");
        pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        yourTabPage.Controls.Add(pb);
```

But if your sole purpose for the tab page is displaying an image, you better use the 'BackgroundImage' of the tabpage itself and use its `BackgroundImageLayout` to maintain image size, this saves a bit of hassel compared to adding a `PictureBox`